# Website with only VW unit, but need to stop the expansion

Tags: html, css, viewport

I’m a designer and need help to fix a problem I got on my website. To ensure the design stays consistent, I used only VW unit (no PX unit at all).

It’ great because I can resize the browser window and the design always fit (critical for my project).

BUT I’m looking for a solution to “block” the expansion of the elements when the browser window becomes too wide. Between 0 to 1’000 pixel wide, everything is OK. Beyond 1’000 px, the elements become too big and at 2’000 it’s awful.

Can I add a `@media` that tell the browser: “Above 1’000 px wide, you don’t scale the element anymore”.

Or is there a parameter like “initial-scale” or “zoom” or any other one I can play with to resolve this?

I can use a `max-width: 1000px` on the body”, but because all the elements are set with VW unit, they will continue to grow anyway.

[Website](http://www.jybe.ch/characters): 
[CSS code](http://www.jybe.ch/characters/_css/global.css) :

— — —

And if there is no real solution (and because I need to rebuild the website from scratch once because I want to improve my CSS knowledge and clean my code), what should I do on my V2 to manage this problem, but keep using this so convenient VW unit?

(be tolerant with my code because I’m mostly a designer :(

Don’t hesitate to ask me questions if you need any other information. Thank you for your attention, and all the best! :)

Jean-Baptiste (Geneva)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you should write `@media` query that will solve your problem easily and code will shorter. Your using `VW` unit which is great practice as it's resizing your components as per your viewport width(VW). Instead of re-writing whole code from scratch you can add media queries but if you want to improve your knowledge it's great to do it from scratch as practice makes man perfect Best luck

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Yes the @media is a solution (probably the one I'll got to use), but it mens that I'll got to set every parameter one-by-one again. The best for me would be a solution where I can say : "OK, now you divide every VW value by 50%" and with this command everything is half big".